# Sliding Window / Grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that there is a lot of information out there on sliding windows and I am not getting the result I was looking for. I am not sure I full understand the process behind the numpy functions that are used and I am hoping someone can explain it better.

What I hoping to do it create a sliding window of various sizes i.e 3x3 4x4 and so on for spatial analysis work. What I have is a raster that has been turned to an array:

```
RasterArray = [[1,2,3,1],     
               [4,3,2,5],
               [3,4,2,3],
               [3,2,4,5]]
```

This raster is a multidimensional array with 4x4

I would like to have a sliding window say 3x3 to go through the array and return the values above and below where prudent

For the example:

```
[[1,2],
 [4,3]]

[[1,2,3],
 [4,3,2]]

[[2,3,1],
 [3,2,5]]

[[3,1],
 [2,5]]

[[1,2],
 [4,3],
 [3,4]]

[[1,2,3],
 [4,3,2],
 [3,4,2]]
```

And so on

If someone could explain more thoroughly how to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what you've described in your example can be done with simple slicing RasterArray[:2,:2] ..[:2,:3] ..[:2,1:4] .. [:2,2:4] ..[:3,:2] ..[:3,:3] and you can get index of values with np.where(RasterArray[:2,:2] > max_val) etc. Maybe you need some more explanation about what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah, your examples make no sense. You have 2x2, 2x3, 3x2 and 3x3 arrays in there, with no apparent logic behind them. So what's 3x3 if not the size of your examples? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: There is a slight logic behind it. If the top left hand corner is the center value of the 3x3 array. Only 4 numbers can be attained (This includes the center value) due to non existant values above or to the left. So the top left hand corner is a 2x2. It follows through respectively as the array carries on.

Comment: as a suggestion, you might want to give an example ignoring edge affects since they tend to be an after thought or ignored in many raster analyses.  Alternately, array padding is/can be used.  It is the changes in the moving/sliding window size that is throwing people off.

Comment: What is the mean of `and return the values above and below where prudent`

Comment: @Jake OK, I understand your example now. I even suspected that part of your window might be missing, but I didn't realize the defining aspect of "move the center of the window along each element". Hmm...so how does this work with a 4x4 window?